# How do I run a phpunit test on Redis pub/sub?

Tags: laravel, redis, phpunit

I'm building a messenger system with Redis publishing on the Laravel end and subscribing on a node server. I would like to test what is stored in the redis pub method using PHPUnit, but I have no idea where to start.

**Controller**

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Conversation $conversation, Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $message = Message::create([
            'body' => $request->input('message'),
            'conversation_id' => $conversation->id,
            'sender_id' => $user->id,
            'type' => 'user_message'
        ]);
             
        $redis = Redis::connection();
            
        $data = new MessageResource($message);

        $redis->publish('message', $data);

    }
}
```

**Current Test**

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_send_a_message()
{
    $this->actingAs($user = User::factory()->create());

    $message = Message::factory()->make(['sender_id' => $user->id]);

    $conversation Conversation::factory()->create();

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/message/'. $conversation->id, ['message' => $message->body])
        ->assertStatus(201);
    
    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        'data' => [
            'body',
            'sender',
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to see is if message has been published on Redis. I'm unsure how to do this, and I think you would probably need to clear the message from Redis after, would you not?

Comment: This might be an unpopular (wrong even for some) opinion but i think you're way out of scope for what a unit test is or should be. You're essentially testing Redis ability to store a data structure which is not your responsibility. In the specific case you posted, if anything, i would assert for the invocation of the `publish` method on your `$redis` instance with a expected `$data` given your request information. A nice side effect of doing this would be that it would force you to extract the redis dependency, use DI and actually mock Redis.

Comment: I only slightly follow you here. Can you provide me some docs to give me context?

Comment: Also another thing to be thought of here is that redis needs to be cleared after tests are done. That might be another question entirely though

Comment: @nitrin0 is right, you should mock/spy Redis and see if `publish` got called with correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test should be like this:

```php
public function test_a_user_can_send_a_message()
{
    $redisSpy = Redis::spy();

    $redisSpy->shouldReceive('connection')->andReturnSelf();

    $this->actingAs($user = User::factory()->create());

    $message = Message::factory()->make(['sender_id' => $user->id]);

    $conversation = Conversation::factory()->create();

    $this->postJson("/api/message/{$conversation->id}", ['message' => $message->body]);

    $this->assertDatabaseCount('messages', 1);

    $redisSpy->shouldHaveReceived('publish')
        ->with('message', new MessageResource(Message::first()));
}
```

As you can see, I have added `Redis::spy();` this is going to allow is to "spy" what is called from `Redis`. You can still *mock* methods, and we have to do so, because you use `Redis::connect();` and then `$redis->publish(...)`, so we will return the *spy* when `connect` is called, that is why we do `shouldReceive('connection')->andReturnSelf()`.

At the end of the code, we check that `$redis->publish` was called with parameters `'message'` and a resource with the desired message. Both must match for this assertion to pass, else you will see a mock error.

Comment: Please take some time to explain your answer and the changes you made to the original code. Code-only answers are less likely to be helpful to both the person asking the question, and future visitors.